# How to verify connection-pool usage in redis-jedis springboot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, connection-pooling, jedis

We have a spring based rest application which fetches data from Redis, we are using spring-data-redis and jedis library to work with Redis-Cluster.
Now we are adding jedis connection pool with below configuration.

```
 JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        // Configure the connection pool properties
        // For example, you can set maxTotal, maxIdle, etc.
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(10);
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(5);
```

I printed the thread name when request is coming on Controller and when redis-template fetching the data by provided key.

I notice that both the thread are printing the same name, like below

```
> 13:46:37.014 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
> o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening RedisConnection
> 13:46:37.344 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
> o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Closing Redis Connection
> 13:46:37.416 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
> o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening RedisConnection
> 13:46:37.543 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
> o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Closing Redis Connection
> 13:46:37.616 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
> o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening RedisConnection
> 13:46:37.742 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
> o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Closing Redis Connection
> 13:46:37.812 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
> o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening RedisConnection
> 13:46:37.940 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
> o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Closing Redis Connection
> 13:46:38.003 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
> o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening RedisConnection
> 13:46:38.128 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
> o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Closing Redis Connection
> 13:46:38.201 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
> o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening RedisConnection
> 13:46:38.337 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
> o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils
```

**Now I am in doubt if jedis using connection from pool or not? Is there any way to verify it Or is there any way we can get the connection-pool usage from `redisTemplate`?**